# Creating scatter points on a multi line chart

Tags: d3.js, scatter-plot, linechart

So I'm using code based off of this..

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955

Essentially, what I'm trying to do is at every data point I want to add a circle. Any help would be much appreciated seeing that I have no idea where to start.

This is my code so far: It worked when I was using single lines.

```
var circlegroup = focus.append("g")
circlegroup.attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
circlegroup.selectAll('.dot')
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr('class', 'dot')
    .attr("cx",function(d){ return x(d.date);})
    .attr("cy", function(d){ return y(d.price);})
    .attr("r", function(d){ return 4;})
    .on('mouseover', function(d){ d3.select(this).attr('r', 8)})
    .on('mouseout', function(d){ d3.select(this).attr('r', 4)});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need [nested selections](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/) for this. Assuming that `data` is a two-dimensional array, you would do something like this.

```
var groups = svg.selectAll("g").data(data).enter().append("g");
groups.data(function(d) { return d; })
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      // set attributes
```

Comment: Thanks, still not able to get it though. What else would have to be there If I wanted to add circles in data point  on this graph (http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955). Also what would I have to put to set the x and y coords, right now no circle is showing up. d3 is still pretty new for me and I'm really confused. Thanks